# Basic statistics function on certain attributes stops at 6% on certain layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, statistics

I am trying to use the basic statistics function in QGIS on an attribute in a vector shapefile but it reaches 6% and then gets stuck and does not load anymore.

It works fine on other layers/other attributes within the same layer, how can I get around this?

There are 335 records in the shapefile and it's point data.

Comment: Please edit your question to specify the software you are using.

Comment: Please also edit to specify that it's a shapefile (in the question body), the topology class of the shapefile, the number of records in the shapefile, and whether the shapefile has been validated.

Comment: I have edited it to answer your questions as best I can - thank you!

Comment: As @Vince mentioned, you may need to check if the geometry of the shapefile is error free, otherwise it could affect the Basic Statistics tool. You can try running `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometry Validity` or the more advanced **Geometry Checker** plugin from `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`. If there are errors then this would need to be cleaned by tools such as GRASS `v.clean` from the _Processing Toolbox_.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I have just checked the geometry validity and there are 0 errors.